# select max 'rental price' for each (car, model)

Tags: sql, oracle

I've go two tables;

Table A:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+
| rentID | carNumber | rentalPrice |
+--------+-----------+-------------+
| Q16    | 2255DFS   |        1150 |
| Q14    | 1104RDC   |         250 |
| Q02    | 1475MHG   |         447 |
| Q11    | 8552FCG   |         214 |
+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

Table B:

```
+---------+------------+--------+
| number  |   brand    | model  |
+---------+------------+--------+
| 2255FDS | AUDI       | A3     |
| 1104RDC | AUDI       | A4     |
| 1475MHG | VOLKSWAGEN | PASSAT |
| 8552FCG | VOLKSWAGEN | POLO   |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

I need to get the maximum rentalPrice for each car brand and model, the rentID, the car brand and the car model.

With the given tables, the output I want to get is:

1. Q16 AUDI A3 1150
2. Q02 VOLKSWAGEN PASSAT 447

So far I got this:

```
SELECT c.brand, c.model,
       MAX(r.rentalPrince) AS maxRentalPrice

FROM ( RENTAL_DETAILS R
  INNER JOIN CAR C ON c.number = r.carNumber )

GROUP BY c.brand, c.model;
```

But if I try to select the rentID aswell I just get all the rents that are in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions:

```
SELECT rc.*
FROM (SELECT c.brand, c.model, r.*,
             MAX(r.rentalPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY c.brand, c.model) as max_rp
      FROM RENTAL_DETAILS r INNER JOIN
           CAR c
           ON c.number = r.carNumber
     ) rc
WHERE rentalPrice = max_rp;
```

Comment: With 'r.*' it shows all the columns that the table has, but my original table has 5 columns and I only want to select 'rentID' and 'rentalPrice'. How can I do that?

Comment: @Cpastor27 . . . Just select the columns that you want, in either the inner query or the outer one.  The `*` is just a convenience, because selecting columns is not really related to the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a subquery to first find the max rental price, then use the result of this to drive a query for the columns of interest?

```
select r.rentalPrice, c.brand, c.model, r.rentID
from cars c 
join rentals r on c.carNumber = r.number
where r.rentalPrice in (
  select max(r.rentalPrice) 
  from rentals r
  join cars c on r.number = c.carNumber 
  group by c.brand, c.model);
```

If you have >1 rental at the same max price this might not give the correct result however.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem I'm facing now, I get 9 rows when I'm supposed to get 8.

Comment: There's the same rentalPrice for two cars of the same brand and model.

Comment: If we are expecting only one row per combination of car brand & model, e.g. one row for Audi A3, but this car was rented at the same max price in 2x transactions, then won't you EXPECT 2x values for rentID?

Comment: yeah, I was wrong, I got an AUDI A4 which was rented 2 times and the max price is the same for both, but each transaction has a different rentID, so I think it's working properly.

Comment: tysm btw, i was struggling with this for like 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
(SELECT 
    Brand 
    ,carNumber 
    ,rentalprice
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY rentalprice DESC) AS highest 
FROM 
    dbo.Table_A
JOIN dbo.Table_B ON Number=carNumber) filterdtable
WHERE filterdtable.highest = 1
```

Used a derived table to filter the results. Hope this helps!